# How to release binaries on Github for different platforms as separate downloads?

Tags: git, github, command-line, software-distribution

I found this at github https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software. Their page provide a way to attach binaries to a special release. My build script compiles binaries for Windows MacOS and Linux.
How to supply seperate downloads for different platforms there? AS far I can see these releases are simple git tags. Is it practicable to realise this with orphan git branches and attach binaries via commandline? I like to use a build, pack and distribution script instead of attaching binaries manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All* Releases are tied to Git tags. You can either choose an existing tag, or let GitHub create a new tag from an existing branch when the Release is created.

You can create releases and attach one or more artifacts (e.g., your binaries) via the GitHub API; see the docs on:

- [Create a release](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#create-a-release)
- [Upload a release asset](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#upload-a-release-asset)

Comment: this looks promising. Thnx